# Neo4j how to create a property set, with out duplicate values unlike a List

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a :hobby relation between :User nodes.

The hobby relation contains a List property `{ hobbies:['football','hockey'] }`

Now I am iterating through a data stream and i want to uniquely merge the hobbies into this List (Like a set). I tried using coalesce like this:

```
MERGE  (from)-[rel:hobbies]->(to)
set rel.hobbies= COALESCE(rel.hobbies, []) + 'football';
```

The problem is that now my property contains duplicates

`{ hobbies:['football','hockey','football'] }`

How can i avoid duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Cypher query should work without need of APOC procedures.

```
MERGE (from)-[rel:hobbies]->(to)
WITH rel, COALESCE(rel.hobbies, []) + 'football' AS hobbies
UNWIND hobbies as r
WITH rel, collect(distinct r) AS unique
set rel.hobbies = unique
```

This query use [UNWIND](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/unwind/) to expand the hobbies array and after it [collect](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/#functions-collect) the unique hobbies into an variable called `unique`. If you don't have APOC procedures in your Neo4j Server use this query.

Comment: Thank you for this insight of UNWIND usage.

Answer (score 1):

[UPDATED]

This query will add 'football' to the `hobbies` collection only if it does not already exist (by doing a check first):

```
MERGE (from)-[rel:hobbies]->(to)
FOREACH(x in CASE WHEN NOT ('football' IN rel.hobbies) THEN [1] END |
  SET rel.hobbies = COALESCE(rel.hobbies, []) + 'football')
```

Instead of hardcoding the hobby to add (e.g., 'football'), you should use a [parameter](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/parameters/).

Also, you should consider altering your data model to use `Hobby` nodes to represent the different hobbies, which is a more graph-oriented approach.

Comment: Thanks ! Will there be a performance impact in using FOREACH ? Also the approach of altering data model to represent hobbies for each node was insightful.

Comment: this is not working when i am creating the relation for the first time.